# Number Sequence (yet again?)

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

This number sequence has numbers rounded to the nearest tenth.

> 1, 2, 4.5, ?, 26, ?

Find the pattern and the answers to the question marks rounded to the nearest tenth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it's been about 10 days since I asked this question, and @hexomino is close, but is not correct, so I'm just going to reveal it.

> $$a_{n} =\frac{n^n}{n!}$$

And, plugging in, we get

> 1, 2, 4.5, **10.7**, 26, **64.8**

(Though I don't know how @hexomino managed to get such a close answer)

Answer (score 2):

Based on OP's hint in the comments I have a new answer

> Looking at a binomial transform of the factorial numbers $$ a_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k} k!$$ for the numbers $n=2,3,4,\ldots$, we get the sequence 2, 4, 9, 21, 52, 134,...
>  Taking half of each of those numbers we get the sequence 1, 2, 4.5, **10.5**, 26, **67**,...
>  which seems to be the sequence we are looking for.
>  In summary, the $n$th term of the sequence is given by $$ a_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2 \rfloor} \binom{n+1}{2k} \frac{k!}{2}$$

**Previous Answer**
Here's a recursive linear relationship (with rounding)

> $a_{n+1} = 2.48 a_n - 0.5$ (rounded to the nearest tenth)

Worked out

> $(2.48 \times 1) - 0.5 = 1.98 \rightarrow 2.0$
>  $(2.48 \times 2) - 0.5 = 4.46 \rightarrow 4.5$
>  $(2.48 \times 4.5) - 0.5 = 10.66 \rightarrow 10.7$
>  $(2.48 \times 10.7) - 0.5 = 26.036 \rightarrow 26.0$
>  $(2.48 \times 26) - 0.5 = 63.98 \rightarrow 64.0$

So the full sequence is

> 1, 2, 4.5, **10.7**, 26, **64**

Comment: No, the numbers were close to correct, but theres a simpler direct function. Hint: rot13(Vg unf fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu snpgbevnyf.)

Comment: Don't think too hard about binomials. There's a very simple function you missed, involving only powers and factorials.